# Mod Rewrite Rule

Tags: mod-rewrite

Hi can anybody help me with this rewrite rule.

Basically i have a url http://mydomain.com/http://somewhere.com/photo.gif which i want it to be forwarded to this url: http://mydomain.com/upload.php?url=http://somewhere.com/photo.gif

I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ upload.php?code=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added a `/`  for `upload.php?...`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /upload.php?code=$1 [L]` will work if you can avoid the **http://** in  `http://somewhere.com`while passing to`http://mydomain.com/http://somewhere.com/`

Comment: @Mozammil RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /upload.php?code=http://$1 [L]  will add that http:// for redirecting... but it's  rejecting anything that's incoming with "http://".  Can't you do str_replace or suitable alternative on the addresses to remove 'http://' from that path.

Comment: @Mozammil Consider accepting this as solution if it worked out for you.